# When to use "had" plus past participle and simple past

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

Which is correct?

> A. Elizabeth I.  had reigned as queen of England from 1558 to 1603.
>   B. Elizabeth I. reigned as queen of England from 1558 to 1603.

My answer is B but as per correction of the head coordinator (ESL School) the answer is A.

Comment: "Correct" is a meaningless concept here. We use Past Perfect to refer to events which occurred ***before*** the "current narrative time" - but that would have to be established by surrounding context, which isn't provided.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please see also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no context, the second one is definitely the correct choice here as there is only one action or event that took place independent of another 'earlier' past action/event.

It is tempting to think that while present perfect is usually used for "a period of time from past to present," the same cannot be applied to past perfect, at least not in all of its usages. While we say "We have finished three assignments today," we do not say "We had finished three assignments that day," unless there is another event that took place after it, as in "Before we went out to the park, we had finished three assignments."

Answer (score 0):

B is the correct answer. It's just telling something about the past. Not connected to any other past action.
compare 'Having finished dinner we went home.
        'After we finished dinner we went home. ( need not use 'had' with 'after' 
         and 'before')